# vagrant - The capability 'nfs_mount' could not be found

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, nfs, vagrant-windows, vagrant-plugin

The capability 'nfs_mount' could not be found. This is an internal error
that users should never see. Please report a bug.

```
Cmd

C:\var\www\cc-dev-env>vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/trusty64' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    default: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
    default: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
    default: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
    default: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
    default: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
    default: your host and reload your VM.
    default:
    default: Guest Additions Version: 4.3.36
    default: VirtualBox Version: 5.0
==> default: [vagrant-hostsupdater] Checking for host entries
==> default: [vagrant-hostsupdater]   found entry for: 192.168.100.100 cc.dev
==> default: Mounting NFS shared folders from guest...
The capability 'nfs_mount' could not be found. This is an internal error
that users should never see. Please report a bug.
```

I am using 
Windows 10 64-bit
Vagrant 1.8.1
vagrant-hostsupdater (1.0.2)
vagrant-nfs_guest (0.1.8)
vagrant-share (1.1.5, system)
vagrant-winnfsd (1.1.0)

Of course I would like to not see this error and see the VM that I am trying to boot open.

Comment: did you try to update your guest additions ? can you change from `type: 'nfs_guest'` to default `type: 'nfs'` can see if you have the same issue or not. If you do it means it would be an issue with the box (maybe nfsd is missing) , it it works, its an issue with the plugin and you probably do not need it

Comment: That did get me past this part for sure. Although when doing a `vagrant destroy` it said `nfs_unmount could not be found` Still, as we know its a problem with the box and not the plugin I believe.

Comment: can you delete the `vagrant.d` directory and retry vagrant up/destroy (still using 'nfs', not yet on `nfs_guest') I am not sure its the box, I don't have windows machine to test but its pretty widely used box

Comment: Thanks for the help. I believe that there is no nfs plugin for windows so I've been using `vagrant-winnfsd` i've delete the vagrant folders though, both in my user root and the folder root. I couldn't install something like `vagrant-nfs`

Comment: well, you would need `vagrant-winnfsd` as as you say windows does not come with its own nfs server, but I am not sure why you'd need `vagrant-nfs_guest` ubuntu box should come with nfsd installed (and running, if not vagrant will start the service when a sync folder is of nfs type)

Comment: Apparently "nfs_guest is a special type of shared folder (provided by a plugin) which understands that the files are IN THE VM, not on the host. If the type was simply ‘NFS’ (supported by vagrant - tho not on windows), the files would live on the HOST (== bad performance)" From my friend who wrote this for his Mac iOS Not sure if that makes sense.

Comment: You could try deleting the `.vagrant.d` folder on the user's directory.

Comment: When I remove the `.vagrant.d` folder it re-downloads all of the dependencies. Should this help me?